# How to get sdcard path for supporting all android device

Tags: android

Can anybody tell How to get sdcard path for supporting all android device.

I have used Environment.getDirectories() but it is not supporting in 4.4.2

Thanks

Comment: That is impossible. So forget it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the benefit of a doubt....new to all aspects, including technology.  Wording for Google searches takes tactic, but this one I thought was basic.  Try what  @JustDanyul posted or this:  (Google search "get sdcard path for android device")

https://source.android.com/devices/storage/